# Firestore on Flutter app requires the [DEFAULT] Firebase app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on Flutter module, that will use some of Firebase tools underneath. Because this module might be used in other projects, I want to have a Firebase app with non `[DEFAULT]` name. All good so far, however `FirebaseFirestore` is still trying to reach out to `[DEFAULT]` app.

```dart
final getIt = GetIt.instance;

void main() {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   
   // ...

   await Firebase.initializeApp(name: "module", options: 
   DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

   // ...

   await DI.setupDependencies("module");
}
```

Inside `DI.setupDependencies(...)`

```dart
final app = Firebase.app(firebaseAppName);

getIt.registerSingleton(FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(app: app));
getIt.registerSingleton(FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: app));
getIt.registerSingleton(FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: app));
// NOTE: Not supported with custom firebase app name
// getIt.registerSingleton(FirebaseAnalytics.instanceFor(app: app));
// getIt.registerSingleton(FirebaseCrashlytics.instance);

final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: app);
fs.collection("users").id; // Exception here
getIt<FirebaseFirestore>().collection("users").id; // This also does not work and throws the same exception
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
E/flutter ( 8030): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
E/flutter ( 8030): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.app
method_channel_firebase.dart:193
E/flutter ( 8030): #1      Firebase.app
firebase.dart:56
E/flutter ( 8030): #2      FirebaseFirestorePlatform.instance
platform_interface_firestore.dart:41
E/flutter ( 8030): #3      new FirebaseFirestorePlatform.instanceFor
platform_interface_firestore.dart:33
E/flutter ( 8030): #4      FirebaseFirestore._delegate
firestore.dart:50
E/flutter ( 8030): #5      FirebaseFirestore.collection
firestore.dart:71
E/flutter ( 8030): #6      DI.setupDependencies
di.dart:34
E/flutter ( 8030): #7      main
```

It fails here:

```dart
/// Returns a [FirebaseAppPlatform] by [name].
///
/// Returns the default Firebase app if no [name] is provided and throws a
/// [FirebaseException] if no app with the [name] has been created.
@override
FirebaseAppPlatform app([String name = defaultFirebaseAppName]) {
  if (appInstances.containsKey(name)) {
    return appInstances[name]!;
  }

  throw noAppExists(name);
}
```

UPD:

Just tried the same with `FirebaseStorage` and it works good, e.g.:

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(name: "module", options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

final fs = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(app: Firebase.app('module'));
logger.info((await fs.ref('test.png').getDownloadURL()));
```

Comment: Have you configured google-services.json?

Comment: Yes, I did configured google-services.json